# Angular 4 Material DatePicker is not opening at correct position

Tags: angular, datepicker, material-design, angular-material

I am using Material Datepicker component (2.0.0-beta.6) in my app. I can able to add it properly, but whenever I open it, it open at the top left corner of the page. Ideally it should open beside the datepicker component.

Please see the code below.

**Demo.html**

```
    <div class="col col-2 col-spacing">
        <md-input-container>
          <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="endDatepicker" placeholder="End Date:">
          <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="endDatepicker"></button>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-datepicker #endDatepicker></md-datepicker>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**DemoModule.ts**

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { DemoComponent} from './demo.component';
import { MaterialModule, MdNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DemoComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    MdNativeDateModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [DemoComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**DemoComponent.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
     selector: 'sbom-search-panel',
     templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
})

export class DemoComponent {}
```

Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to import `MdDatepickerModule` since `MaterialModule` is deprecated..

Comment: Yes, I tried with this but no luck. I tried the same thing in separate project and it is working fine. I think there is some issues with the CSS file created by me. Some properties are going to be overlap with datepicker CSS. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Did you tried beta.8 ?, This issue should be solved in the latest release.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, This issue was because some CSS. I correct and it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try to put `[touchUi]="true"` on the tag `md-datepicker`. It should work!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, This issue was because some CSS. I correct and it is working fine for me.

Comment: @Dat Nguyen => thank for this idea, it renders a little better

Comment: @Deunz - Actually some of our custom css classes were override over material css classes. After removing those classes it started working properly.

Comment: in case anyone has the same issue, the wrong css I had was `.mat-input-underline, .mat-form-field-underline` with display none

Answer (score 0):

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import 'hammerjs';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MdDatepickerModule, MdNativeDateModule, MdInputModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdInputModule,
    /*Datepickar */
    MdDatepickerModule,
    MdNativeDateModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> **Demo**

[image]